# Toggle button in one table when its data is copied to another

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6, html-table

I have two tables - one with a list and the other an empty favourites table.

The user can click 'Add' on rows in the first table to add them to the favourites. The 'Add' button then disappears.

The favourites row renders with a 'Remove' button, and sure enough, removes the row from the favourites table if clicked.

What I want to do is have the item's  'Add' button reappear in the first table if the item is removed from the favourites table (so that the user has the option to re-add it) but I can't figure out how to establish a connection between the tables to make it work.

```
// render search results to first table

const renderData = () => {
  tableData.forEach(repo => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.className = "resultRow";
    row.innerHTML = `
      <td><a href=${repo.url} target='_blank'>${repo.name}</a></td>
      <td>${repo.language}</td>
      <td>${repo.tag}</td>
      <td class='cell'><button type='button' class='add-btn'>${
        repo.add
      }</button></td>
    `;
    repoTable.appendChild(row);
  });


  // add event listener to 'Add' button. Hide 'Add' button when item is added to favourites

  addBtnArr = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("add-btn"));
  addBtnArr.map(i => {
    i.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let userFave = tableData[addBtnArr.indexOf(i)];
      i.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      console.log(userFave)
      addToFavourites(userFave);
    });
  });

};


// copy item to favourites table

const addToFavourites = rowData => {
  console.log(rowData);
  let faveRow = document.createElement("tr");
  faveRow.className = "favesRow";
  rowData.add = "Remove";
  faveRow.innerHTML = `
      <td><a href=${rowData.url} target='_blank'>${rowData.name}</a></td>
      <td>${rowData.language}</td>
      <td>${rowData.tag}</td>
      <td class='cell'><button type='button' class='remove-btn'>${
        rowData.add
      }</button></td>
 `;
  favesTable.appendChild(faveRow);
  hideSingleFave(favesTable);


  // add event listener to 'Remove' button. Remove corresponding row from favourites when clicked

  let removeBtn = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("remove-btn"));
  removeBtn.map(i => {
    i.addEventListener("click", () => {
      i.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the following approach. Add an id to every **Add Button** in the first table which uniquely identifies it. Something like **index-add**, so your button would have ids like 0-add, 1-add, 2-add and so on.

When you click on a button apply the hidden class to that button. Say if you clicked 0-add class hidden would be added to it which would hide the button.
And data-add-target = "0-add" in remove button. When you click on remove button read data-add-target attribute and remove the class hidden from that target button.

Essentially your buttons would look something like

```
<button id="0-add">Add</button>
```

Once this button is clicked it gets hidden and in fav table, a row appears with the remove button

```
<button id="0-add" class = "hidden">Add</button>
<button data-add-target="0-add">Remove</button>
```

Once you click on remove button, remove the hidden class from data-add-target.

```
<button id="0-add">Add</button>
```